# comparing 2 list indexes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem with comparing 2 list indexes.
In code

```
inventory=['q', 'w', 'e', 'r']

print(inventory)

if 'q' and 'w' in inventory:

    a=inventory.index('q')
    b=inventory.index('w')
else:
    print('\nNothing')
if a > b:
    a+=1
    del inventory[:a]
    print("Your inventory:")
    print(inventory)
    print(a)
elif b<a:
    b+=1
    del inventory[:b]
    print("Your inventory:")
    print(inventory)
    print(b)
else:
    print('Sth went wrong')
    print(a,b)
```

`a` and `b` don't want to compare -output from console is :

    `['q', 'w', 'e', 'r']
    Sth went wrong
    0 1`

It seams, that 2 ints are unable to compare. Does anybody know why?

Comment: Not strictly related to your problem, but `'q' and 'w' in inventory` doesn't do what you think it does. Do `inventory = ["w"]` and `'q' and 'w' in inventory` will still evaluate to True.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `if` statement you have

```
if a > b:
    ...
elif b < a:
    ...
```

These are the same thing. The second condition should be `b > a:`

Comment: Thank you. I didn't see it earlier :)

Comment: now you can accept the answer.

Comment: We don't usually bother writing full answers to typo questions because they're unlikely to help future readers with a similar problem: they're unlikely to find this question by Googling. So the system automatically deletes closed typo questions after a few days, but upvoted / accepted answers block that process.